# Arnold's Cat Map

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, image-processing, linear-algebra, repeated-transformation

#### Challenge

Given a colour raster image* with the same width and height, output the image transformed under [*Arnold's cat map*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold%27s_cat_map). (*details see below)

#### Definition

Given the size of the image `N` we assume that the coordinates of a pixel are given as numbers between `0` and `N-1`.

*Arnold's cat map* is then defined as follows:

A pixel at coordinates `[x,y]` is moved to `[(2*x + y) mod N, (x + y) mod N]`.

This is nothing but a linear transform on torus: The yellow, violet and green part get mapped back onto the initial square due to the `mod N`.

[image: visualization]

This map (let's call it `f`) has following properties:

- It is *bijective*, that means reversible: It is a linear transformation with the matrix `[[2,1],[1,1]]`. Since it has determinant `1` and and it has only integer entries, the inverse also has only integer entries and is given by `[[1,-1],[-1,2]]`, this means it is also bijective on integer coordinates.
- It is a *torsion* element of the group of bijective maps of `N x N` images, that means if you apply it sufficiently many times, you will get the original image back: `f(f(...f(x)...)) = x` The amount of times the map applied to itself results in the identity is guaranteed to be less or equal to `3*N`. In the following you can see the image of a cat after a given number of iterated applications of *Arnold's cat map*, and an animation of what a repeated application looks like:

[image: multiple repeated applications]
[image]

#### Details

- Your program does not necessarily have to deal with images, but 2D-arrays/matrices, strings or similar 2D-structures are acceptable too.
- It does not matter whether your `(0,0)` point is on the bottom left or on the top left. (Or in any other corner, if this is more convenient in your language.) **Please specify what convention you use in your submission.**

#### Testcases

In matrix form (`[1,2,3,4]` is the top row, `1` has index `(0,0)`, `2` has index `(1,0)`, `5` has index `(0,1)`)

```
 1     2     3     4
 5     6     7     8
 9    10    11    12
13    14    15    16

maps to:

 1    14    11     8
12     5     2    15
 3    16     9     6
10     7     4    13

 --------------------

 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9

 map to:

 1     8     6
 9     4     2
 5     3     7
```

As image (bottom left is `(0,0)`):

[image][image]

Comment: Poor Lena. I hope you kept iterating long enough

Comment: Can we take the image size as input?  Is it always square?

Comment: Yes the image is always square, and I'm not sure about the size, is there anything *against* allowing that?

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
Zṙ"JC$µ2¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@x/1cOdMJS9nlUNbjQ4t/P//f3S0oY6RjrGOSaxOtKmOmY65jgWQZaljaKBjaKhjaATkGBrrGJroGJrqGJrFxgIA) The coordinates are as in the answer.

### Explanation

```
      µ2¡   Twice:
Z             Transpose, then
 ṙ"           Rotate rows left by
   JC$          0, -1, -2, -3, …, 1-n units.
```

This wrap-shears the matrix in one direction, then the other.

Comment: Fantastic algorithm!

Answer (score 9):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 23 bytes

```
tt&n:qt&+&y\tb+&y\b*+Q(
```

The `(0,0)` point is upper left, as in the examples in the challenge text.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@19SopZnVViipq1WGVOSBCKTtLQDNf7/jzbUMdIx1jGxVjDVMdMx17GwVrDUMTTQMTTUMTSyVjA01jE00TE01TE0iwUA)

#### Explanation

A matrix in MATL can be indexed with a single index instead of two. This is called **linear indexing**, and uses **column-major** order. This is illustrated by the following 4×4 matrix, in which the value at each entry coincides with its linear index:

```
1   5   9  13
2   6  10  14
3   7  11  15
4   8  12  16
```

There are two similar approaches to implement the mapping in the challenge:

1. Build an indexing matrix that represents Arnold's **inverse mapping** on linear indices, and use it to **select** the values from the original matrix. For the 4×4 case, the indexing matrix would be

   ```
    1  8 11 14
   15  2  5 12
    9 16  3  6
    7 10 13  4
   ```

   telling that for example the original `5` at *x*=2, *y*=1 goes to *x*=3, *y*=2. This operation is called **reference indexing**: use the indexing matrix to tell which element to pick from the original matrix. This is functon `)`, which takes two inputs (in its default configuration).
2. Build an indexing matrix that represents Arnold's **direct mapping** on linear indices, and use it to **write** the values into the original matrix. For the 4×4 case, the indexing matrix would be

   ```
    1 10  3 12
    6 15  8 13
   11  4  9  2
   16  5 14  7
   ```

   telling that the entry *x*=2, *y*=1 of the new matrix will be overwritten onto the entry with linear index `10`, that is, *x*=3, *y*=2. This is called **assignment indexing**: use the indexing matrix, a data matrix and the original matrix, and write the data onto the original matrix at the specified indices. This is function `(`, which takes three inputs (in its default configuration).

Method 1 is more straightforward, but method 2 turned out to be shorter.

```
tt     % Take the input implicitly and push two more copies
&n     % Get its size as two (equal) numbers: N, N
:qt    % Push range [0  1 ... N-1] twice. This represents the original x values
&+     % Matrix of all pairwise additions. This represents x+y
&y     % Push a copy of N onto the top of the stack
\      % Modulo. This is the new y coordinate: y_new
t      % Push another copy
b+     % Bubble up the remaining copy of [0 1 ... N-1] and add. This is 2*x+y
&y     % Push a copy of N onto the top of the stack
\      % Modulo. This is the new x coordinate: x_new
b*+    % Bubble up the remaining copy of N, multiply, add. This computes
       % x_new*N+y_new, which is the linear index for those x_new, y_new 
Q      % Add 1, because MATL uses 1-based indexing
(      % Assigmnent indexing: write the values of the original matrix into
       % (another copy of) the original matrix at the entries given by the
       % indexing matrix. Implicitly display the result
```

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 44 bytes

```
(n=MapIndexed[RotateLeft[#,1-#2]&,#]&)@*n
```

A port of [Lynn's fantastic algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105371/56178). There's an invisible 3-byte character, U+F3C7 in the UTF-8 encoding, before the last `]`; Mathematica renders it as a superscript `T`, and it takes the transpose of a matrix.

## Mathematica, 54 bytes

```
Table[#2[[Mod[2x-y-1,#]+1,Mod[y-x,#]+1]],{x,#},{y,#}]&
```

Unnamed function taking two arguments, a positive integer `#` and a 2D array `#2` of dimensions `#`x`#`, and returning a 2D array of similar shape. As in the given test case, the point with coordinates {0,0} is in the upper left and the x-axis is horizontal. Straightforward implementation using the inverse `[[1,-1],[-1,2]]` mentioned in the question, with a `-1` in the first coordinate to account for the fact that arrays are inherently 1-indexed in Mathematica. If we're not allowed to take the dimension of the matrix as an additional argument, then this solution becomes nine bytes longer (replace the first `#`—not the `#2`—with `a=Length@#` and all the subsequent `#`s with `a`s).

Comment: Dang, beat me to it

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, <s>89</s> <s>82</s> <s>77</s> 73 bytes

```python
def f(a):exec'a=[l[-i:]+l[:-i]for i,l in enumerate(zip(*a))];'*2;return a
```

Input is a list of lists
The string inside the exec transpose the list of lists and cyclically rotate each list by the line index (0 based - 3rd line is rotated 2 times to the right).
This process is done 2 times to the input.

#### +4 bytes that will do the transformation N times

```python
def f(a,n):exec'a=[l[-i:]+l[:-i]for i,l in enumerate(zip(*a))];'*2*n;return a
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 55 bytes

```
m#n|r<-[0..n-1]=[[m!!mod(2*y-x)n!!mod(x-y)n|x<-r]|y<-r]
```

Usage example: `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]] # 4` -> `[[1,14,11,8],[12,5,2,15],[3,16,9,6],[10,7,4,13]]`.

`0,0` is the upper left corner. This uses the inverse transformation.

Answer (score 1):

## ImageJ macro, 29 bytes

```
v=getPixel((x+y)%w,(2*y+x)%h)
```

- Open image of Lena
- From Process menu select Math / Macro...

Comment: Doesn't this perform f^(-1)? It gets the pixel value at the coordinates it is suppossed to *move* it to. You probably mean `v=getPixel((2*y-x)%w,(x-y)%h)`.

Comment: @RobinKoch Thanks, `2*x+y` changed to `2*y+x`

Comment: That's neither what I wrote nor what I meant. You need the inverse transformation for your approach. For `f(x,y) = (2x+y, x+y)` this inverse transformation is described by `f^(-1) = (x-y, 2y-x)`. (My other comment was wrong.) So your code shold be `v=getPixel((x-y)%w,(2*y-x)%h)`.

Comment: I tested my formula and the result is the same as Lena image in the question

Comment: @RobinKoch You can [download ImageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/download.html) and test both formula

Comment: I see. I assumed you use the top left corner as origin as ImageJ does. But apparently you use the bottom left corner as the example does.

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 69 bytes

```python
lambda M:eval("[r[-i:]+r[:-i]for i,r in enumerate(zip(*"*2+"M))]))]")
```

An improvement on [Rod's transpose-and-shift-twice method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105367/20260). Applies the operation `M -> [r[-i:]+r[:-i]for i,r in enumerate(zip(*M))]` twice by creating and evaluating the string

```python
[r[-i:]+r[:-i]for i,r in enumerate(zip(*[r[-i:]+r[:-i]for i,r in enumerate(zip(*M))]))]
```

This narrowly beats out a direct transformation (70 bytes), assuming the image is square and its length can be taken as input:

```python
lambda M,n:[[M[(2*j-i)%n][(i-j)%n]for i in range(n)]for j in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 160

Golfed:

```java
int[][]f(int[][]m){int x=0,y,l=m.length,r[][]=new int[l][];for(;x<l;++x)r[x]=new int[l];for(x=0;x<l;++x)for(y=0;y<l;++y)r[(x+y)%l][(2*x+y)%l]=m[y][x];return r;}
```

Ungolfed:

```java
  int[][] f(int[][] m) {
    int x = 0, y, l = m.length, r[][] = new int[l][];
    for (; x < l; ++x) {
      r[x] = new int[l];
    }
    for (x = 0; x < l; ++x) {
      for (y = 0; y < l; ++y) {
        r[(x + y) % l][(2 * x + y) % l] = m[y][x];
      }
    }
    return r;
  }
```